# Saving and loading data from LocalStorage Python

Tags: python, selenium, get, local-storage, telegram

I'm just starting to learn Python and I couldn't find the answer to my question anywhere, I hope for your help)
I wanted to automate authorization in Telegram when logging in through webdriver selenium
But Telegram has authorization data stored in local storage instead of cookies.

I am using this code to save cookies:

```
pickle.dump(driver.get_cookies(), open(f"{Login1}_cookies", "wb"))
```

Maybe someone knows the code for saving data from Local Storage?

Comment: maybe you should run `Selenium` with `profile` which have this data in `LocalStorage`

Comment: I'm not sure but it may need to use `JavaScript` and `driver.execute_script()` to access data in `LocalStore`

Comment: as I know browsers Chrome/Firefox keep some information in database files `sqlite` and you can use standard module `sqlite3` to read data from these files. But running browser may block access to files and it may not  have permission to write in these file. Besides everytime when you run `Selenium` it may create new profile and you would have to know where it keep files `sqlite`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I saw someone doing as you suggested, but I couldn't do it myself(

Comment: if you tried it then show your code and full error message - maybe you have some small mistake which we can fix.

Comment: other question: why do you use browser to access it? If you want to create bot then there are python modules for this. If you want to automate private account then telegram may block access if it detects it.

Comment: I need many Telegram accounts that I can automatically log into through my program

Comment: Guys, I understand that I'm asking a lot, but so far I have no idea how this can be done, maybe someone already has experience in this and can share the code?

Comment: as for using `profile` I think you may find some questions on Stackoverflow which show it. Different browser may need different `Options`. As for using `execute_script()` it needs to learn JavaScript for details :)

Comment: [Window localStorage Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp)

Answer (score 1):

it turned out to be much easier
If it is useful to someone, you can create a folder for each account

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=D:\\Profile1")
chrome_options=chrome_options
```

After you log in 1 time, the next time the data will be loaded automatically on this path